# No sound after upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10 AMD Ryzen 4500

Tags: upgrade, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.10, amd-ryzen

The sound for my HP Envy X360 has stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10. It was working fine with 20.04. Now the output device is shown as *Dummy output*.

Apparently, [other users have the same issue too](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ji3hlw/no_sound_in_popos_2010_in_my_hp_laptop_envy_x360/), it has been faced by others too and a workaround is to reinstall `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`. However this only works till you reboot.

Is there a permanent fix anyone can suggest or something that I can try?

Comment: have you tried updating the bios since you have upgraded?

Comment: Not really I have updated my bios couple of weeks back, I can check however don't think there is an update available

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found and it seems to work for now even after reboot:

```
sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Uncomment the lines below:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink   
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
```

This answer was found in the [Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1844746#p1844746).

Comment: This solved my problem. Running Pop_OS 20.10 on a Lenovo 430S. Thanks!